# TypeScript compiler API get get type of mapped property

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Given `type Mapping = Record<'success' | 'error', React.ReactNode>`.
How do I get the typescript.Type using the compiler API?

The symbol of `Mapping` has two properties as expected but each property symbol does not have a type.

In { success: React.ReactNode, error: React.ReactNode } you could get the type for each property by using `checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, symbol.declarations[0])` but this doesn
t seem to work for mapped types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works when providing either the name or type node of the type alias for the `node` argument of `TypeChecker#getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, node)`:

```
const mappingDec = sourceFile.statements[0] as ts.TypeAliasDeclaration;
const mappingType = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(mappingDec.name);

// then example use...
for (const prop of mappingType.getProperties()) {
    const name = prop.getName();
    const type = typeChecker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(prop, mappingDec.name)
}
```

Comment: The properties are fine. I'm want the type they're mapped to. Preferably by using the public API.

Comment: @epsilon sorry, I did not read the question right. Use `TypeChecker#getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, node)` and provide either the name or type node of the type alias. I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome. That cleared a lot of things up why #getTypeofSymbolAtLocation exists